# Where can I find the genesis file for mainnet?

Tags: mainnet

I would like to see the genesis file that was used for mainnet.

Answer (score 6):

The genesis file for mainnet can be found here:
https://tezos.foundation/wp-content/uploads/2018/09/5223213-genesis.txt